# How to search name like "shiv k" in solr

Tags: solr

Solr searching fail while I search for a name like "shiv k". But it is indexed in solr like "shiv kumar". While typing it gives me result but when I came to this point during typing "Shiv k" it produces no result. 
Any idea.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. **Fuzzy search** 
   :**q=name:"shiv k"~1.5** it will return matches with a certain confidence. If it doesn't return the excepted text increase the value 1.5 in the query.
2. **Wildcard search** will intercept a partial term and return a list of documents, including some expansion with documents containing
   a term that contains the query term as a substring.
   **q=name:shiv+k*** or try the **q=name:(text1* AND text2*)**